# restrict commands that salt-minion is able to publish

Tags: salt-stack

configured the salt-stack environment like below:

machine1 -> salt-master

machine2 -> salt-minion

machine3 -> salt-minion

This setup is working for me and I can publish i.e. the command "ls -l /tmp/" from **machine2** to **machine3** with
`salt-call publish.publish 'machine3' cmd.run 'ls - /tmp/'`

How it's possible to restrict the commands that are able to be published?

In the currently setup it's possible to execute every command on machine3 and that we would be very risky. I was looking in the salt-stack documentation but unfortunately, I didn't find any example how to configure it accordingly.

SOLUTION:

1. on **machine1** create file **/srv/salt/_modules/testModule.py**
2. insert some code like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

def test():
     return __salt__['cmd.run']('ls -l /tmp/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
     test()
```

3. to distribute the new module to the minions run:

   salt '*' saltutil.sync_modules
4. on **machine2** run:

   salt-call publish.publish 'machine3' testModule.test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [peer configuration](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/peer.html#peer-configuration) in the salt master config can limit what commands certain minion can publish, e.g.

```
peer:
  machine2:
    machine1:      
      - test.*
      - cmd.run
    machine3:      
      - test.*
      - disk.usage
      - network.interfaces
```

This will allow minion `machine2` to publish `test.*` and `cmd.run` commands.

P.S. Allowing minions to publish `cmd.run` command is not a good idea generally, just put it here as example.

Comment: thank you for your hint! But I have a script on the minion machines that I want to execute. I want that is just allowed to execute only this script and nothing else. Do have any idea?

Comment: @CDroescher wrap your script into a salt custom module (literally just need a python function), then only allow that custom module see http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/#modules-are-easy-to-write